# SQL - Removing other entries

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this table (table1):

[image]

I need to know all the 'num' who dont know HTML

I tried - `SELECT num FROM table1 WHERE package <> HTML`

The problem is, for example, that NUM 2 knows Excel aswell, so he still shows up in the result...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT num FROM table1 
WHERE
(num NOT IN (SELECT num FROM table1 WHERE package = 'HTML'))
```

I don't have access to a MySQL box at this moment, but that should work.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT num
FROM table1
WHERE num NOT IN (SELECT num FROM table1 WHERE package = 'HTML')
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way of doing it using `not exists`

```
select 
distinct num from table_name t1
where not exists
(
  select 1 from table_name t2
  where t2.package = 'HTML'
  and t1.num = t2.num
)
```